# Cannot install tokumx on osx: cannot execute binary file

Tags: tokumx

I download from tokumx website newest version. When I start mongod I have an error,

```
bash: ./mongod: cannot execute binary file
```

Any solution.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Tokutek/mongo/issues/1094

Answer (score 0):

The only version available directly from the website is for linux, you'll need to contact them to get an OSX build.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: My answer is "contact them to get an OSX build".

Answer (score 0):

The TokuMX Community Edition downloads featured on the Tokutek site are currently 64-bit Linux only. The [system requirements](http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-installation.html) also note that only 64-bit Linux is officially supported.

However, for OS X users there is a [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) TAP package available if you want to install binaries for development purposes.

Assuming you have have Homebrew installed, you should be able to install the  [`tokumx-bin`](https://github.com/Tokutek/homebrew-tokumx) package by running the following from your shell prompt:

```
brew tap tokutek/tokumx
brew install tokumx-bin
```

Notes:

- the package install will fail unless you enter some text when prompted for an email address (though any text including the default "email address" seems to work)
- the `tokumx-bin` package conflicts with the `mongodb` package as both use the same names for binaries
- TokuMX binaries and data files are *not* interchangeable with MongoDB